# Android Studio Flutter Manifest Multiple Errors

Tags: android, flutter, manifest

I am an intermediate Android Apps developer who uses java. Recently I tried to switch to Flutter and default app works fine debug on my cell phone through cable.

I just happened to look at Android Manifest and there are multiple error showing:

[image]

But to my surprise it shows no error on device.

I have set Flutter, dart and git path already. It would be nice if someone can help with theses errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal since you are operating on a Flutter project, and not an Android one.

Try to Open the project from `your-app-folder/android`.

Comment: Thanks so much, yes no error show if just android project is opened instead whole flutter.. So do I just leave it as it is and keep working on Flutter app?

Comment: Yes, there are actually no errors to worry about. It is just the IDE having a hard time interpreting Android when a Flutter project is open.